# Find a pattern, but not within a C++ comment

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a regex that searches a large codebase for usage of a particular token that used as either a type or a variable.  Let's say the token is "foo" and I want to find it as a work by itself.

My initial regex is this:

```
foo$|foo\s|foo\[|foo\*|<foo|foo>
```

Matches: foo at the end of a line, foo with a space, foo pointer, foo in a collection, etc...

I want to **exclude** instances that are within a C++ comment bock. Such as in the instance below.

```
// consume the foo and read another.
```

I've tried amending the regex using negative lookahead, but that doesn't seem to work

```
(?!\/\/).*(foo$|foo\s|foo\[|foo\*|<foo|foo>)
```

Anyone know how to do this in a regex?

Update:

I just want to casually filter out lines that might have two forward slashes preceeding the target pattern. I don't care about nested comments, C-style comments (/* */), or anything spanning multiple lines.

Comment: That's non-trivial. To reliably detect comments you also have to recognize character and string literals at the same time. Basically what you need to do is write a full C++ lexer.

Comment: By the way, does C++ still support trigraphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fairly comprehensive regex for what you're asking for (tested in Perl):

```perl
my $foo_regex = qr{
    \G
    (?>
        # // comment
        / (?: \\ \n )*+ / (?> \\ \n | [^\n] )*+
    |
        # /* comment */
        / (?: \\ \n )*+ \* (?> .*? \* (?: \\ \n )*+ / )
    |
        # 'c'
        ' (?: [^'\\\n] | \\ . )++ '
    |
        # "string"
        " (?: [^"\\\n] | \\ . )*+ "
    |
        # R"(raw string)"
        \b
        (?: (?> [LU] | u (?: \\ \n )*+ 8?+ ) (?: \\ \n )*+ )?+
        R
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        "
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        ( [^()\\\s]?+ )
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        ( [^()\\\s]?+ )
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        ( [^()\\\s]?+ )
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        ( [^()\\\s]?+ )
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        ( [^()\\\s]?+ )
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        ( [^()\\\s]?+ )
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        ( [^()\\\s]?+ )
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        ( [^()\\\s]?+ )
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        ( [^()\\\s]?+ )
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        ( [^()\\\s]?+ )
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        ( [^()\\\s]?+ )
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        ( [^()\\\s]?+ )
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        ( [^()\\\s]?+ )
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        ( [^()\\\s]?+ )
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        ( [^()\\\s]?+ )
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        ( [^()\\\s]?+ )
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        \(
        (?>
            .*?
            \)
            (?: \\ \n )*+
            \g{-16}
            (?: \\ \n )*+
            \g{-15}
            (?: \\ \n )*+
            \g{-14}
            (?: \\ \n )*+
            \g{-13}
            (?: \\ \n )*+
            \g{-12}
            (?: \\ \n )*+
            \g{-11}
            (?: \\ \n )*+
            \g{-10}
            (?: \\ \n )*+
            \g{-9}
            (?: \\ \n )*+
            \g{-8}
            (?: \\ \n )*+
            \g{-7}
            (?: \\ \n )*+
            \g{-6}
            (?: \\ \n )*+
            \g{-5}
            (?: \\ \n )*+
            \g{-4}
            (?: \\ \n )*+
            \g{-3}
            (?: \\ \n )*+
            \g{-2}
            (?: \\ \n )*+
            \g{-1}
            (?: \\ \n )*+
            "
        )
    |
        # / (not starting a comment)
        / (?! (?: \\ \n )*+ [/*] )
    |
        # identifier
        \w (?: (?: \\ \n )*+ \w )*+
    |
        # arbitrary other character
        [^/"'\w]
    )*?
    \b
    (
        f
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        o
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        o
    )
    (?!
        (?: \\ \n )*+
        \w
    )
}xms;
```

An overview of the complications it takes into account:

- `"foo"`, `'foo'`, `// foo`, `/* foo */` are not occurrences of `foo`, but a string literal, multi-character constant, single-line comment, and a block comment, respectively.
- `/* " */`, `// "`, `" /* "`, `'//'`, etc. are a comment, comment, string literal, and multi-character constant, respectively. What that means is you can't filter out string literals, comments, etc. in stages; you have to parse them all at once in order to avoid mistaking the contents of a quoted construct for the delimiters of another quoted construct.
- Backslash-newline combinations must be ignored (as if they were absent from the source file):

  ```
    /\
    * this is a comment */
    /\
    / and so is this
    foo\
    bar  // this is a single identifier, 'foobar'
    f\
    oo  // ... but this is 'foo'
    "this is a string\\
    " <- that's not the end of the string; this is: "
  ```
- A large part of this regex deals with raw string literals of the form `R"delim(...)delim"` in combination with arbitrary backslash-newline pairs that can be interspersed anywhere. It is fortunate that C++ specifies an upper bound of at most 16 custom delimiter characters; otherwise we would have to use runtime code execution / dynamic regex generation.
- Trigraphs are not handled. If you want to add support, start by changing every occurrence of `\\` in the regex to `(?> \\ | \?\?/ )`.

---

Update: For your simplified requirements (find the word `foo` not preceded by `//` in the string), you can simply do `^(?:[^/]|/(?!/))*?\bfoo\b`.

Comment: Thanks.  The latter expression in your update was what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are not the best tool for this.

I've written a C to Delphi converter (https://github.com/WouterVanNifterick/C-To-Delphi), where I do use regular expressions for certain tasks, but my conclusion is that regular expressions are just not the right tool for what you're trying to do.
I can tell, because I've tried it, and decided to abandon regular expressions because things got over-complicated and things just didn't work reliably.

You can quickly create something that works in 90% of the cases, but if you want to properly deal with nested comments, or strings that look like comments, parsing is the only options.

You don't need a full C++ parser for that. You need to iterate through all characters, and keep track of whether you're in a /* */ block, a "" string block or in a // section or not, and do what you need to do.

Comment: C++ does not have nested comments. (I'd even argue that "nested comment" is an oxymoron.)

Comment: What do you mean? You can have stuff that looks like line comments within block comments.  And you can enclose that within a string. And you can put new block comments around that :)
The point is: that's not the kind of stuff you'd want to do with regular expressions.

Comment: Let me set expectations.  I just want to casually filter out lines that might have two forward slashes preceeding the target pattern. I don't care about nested comments, C-style comments (/* */), or anything spanning multiple lines.

Comment: @Selbie: I understand that you don't especially *care* about strings and nested comments, but the reality is that you cannot ignore them. The regex that you're about to use will treat _anything_ that starts with // as a line comment, which is clearly incorrect. It could be a part of a string for example.

Comment: I should have been very explicit about what I was trying to accomplish. I really should not have ever mentioned "C++" because that pulls in a whole lot different audience and mindset.   What I should have said: "How do I extend a regular expression such that it doesn't match if the pattern occurs after a pair of forward slashes on the same line."